# Fixing key backlight on samsung ativ book 8

Tags: gnome, keyboard, 17.04, backlight

I have got a Samsung ATIV Book 8 but cannot get the key backlight to work on this machine.

The machine has dual graphic setup however the AMD gpu burned out years ago, hence it is switched off in grub and the intel hd4000.

The <kbd>fn</kbd> keys **do** work for wifi, touchpad, projection, screen brightness.

I have tried modifying grub with `acpi_osi=` , `acpi_backlight=intel` as well as numerous other tweaks floating around the web, e.g. installing `xbacklight, samsung-tools` (not supported on 17.04). I am running Ubuntu gnome 17.04.

Messing around in `/sys/class/leds` lists:

```
input3::capslock  input3::numlock  input3::scrolllock  mmc0::  phy0-led
```

I am assuming that the last one is the power led / disk led.

The command `acpi_listen` does not list other <kbd>fn</kbd> combinations with settings or brightness.

Could any of you point me in the right direction or make me understand how and where the keyboard backlight information is located?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by reinstalling Ubuntu in CSM mode. I think there is an issue with uefi and the function keys.